# SQL two or more with same properties

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id  value    has_other  color
1   banana   0          yellow
2   apple    1          red
3   apple    1          green
4   orange   0          orange
5   grape    0          red
6   grape    0          green
```

I want to make a query that selects all entries that has 'has_other' = 0, but there are other entries with same 'value' and 'has_other' value (essentially to find duplicates)

**Edit**: added some entries. Query should return these for above example:

```
5, grape, 0, red
6, grape, 0, green
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: so you want to see: banana, apple, orange; or banana, orange?

Comment: @sqrfv in this example it should return nothing. but if both apples had has_other value 0, it should return those two. i wanna return all has_other = 0, where there exist 2 or more with same value and has_other in table

Comment: @MostyMostacho has_other is either 0 or 1. it's just a bool to see if there should be other entries with same value

Comment: @MostyMostacho that case does not exist in my dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT value
  FROM myTable
  WHERE has_other = 0
  GROUP BY value
  HAVING count(*) > 1
  ) a ON a.value = t.value
WHERE t.has_other = 0;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9842e/1)</kbd>

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! though it works quite slow with +180.000 rows

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from myTable 
where value in (
    select value
    from myTable
    where has_other = 0
    group by value
    having count(*) > 1
)
 and has_other = 0
```

Comment: it seems to be returning the right rows, but only one of each (in above example only one of the grapes)

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you had shown your expected result. I think that you want this result from your data:
[image: expected result]

Well, to obtain a result without duplicates you have to use the `distinct` function. And this is the script:

```
select distinct(f.value), f.has_other
from fruit f
where f.has_other=0
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: this one also return all those entries where only one with the same value exist